# Julia: Difference between Type and DataType

Tags: types, julia

To me they seem to be the same. Since `Type` is of type `DataType` and vice-versa, how are they not equivalent? When should I use one versus the other?

```
> isa(DataType, Type)
true

> typeof(Type)
DataType

> isa(Type, DataType)
true

> typeof(DataType)
DataType
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Type` and `DataType` are themselves both types.  And the type of most types is, as you've found, `DataType`.  In this case, `DataType` is a subtype of the abstract `Type`:

```
julia> supertype(DataType)
Type{T}

julia> supertype(Type)
Any

julia> DataType <: Type
true
```

This means that anything that `isa` `DataType` will also be a `Type` — so many types in Julia <strike>are</strike> `isa` both. There are also other subtypes of `Type`, including `Union`s and `TypeConstructor`s.  This means that *all* types in julia will be of type `Type`, but even simple things like `Vector` won't be of type `DataType`.

`Type` is special. As you see above, it's parametric.  This allows you to precisely specify the type of a specific type in question.  So while every single type in Julia `isa` `Type`, only `Int` `isa` `Type{Int}`:

```
julia> isa(Int, Type{Int})
true

julia> isa(Float64, Type{Int})
false

julia> isa(Float64, Type)
true
```

This ability is special and unique to `Type`, and it's essential in allowing dispatch to be specified on a specific type.  For example, many functions allow you to specify a type as their first argument.

```
f(x::Type{String}) = "string method, got $x"
f(x::Type{Number}) = "number method, got $x"

julia> f(String)
"string method, got String"

julia> f(Number)
"number method, got Number"
```

It's worth noting that `Type{Number}` is *only* the type of `Number`, and not the type of `Int`, even though `Int <: Number`!  This is parametric invariance. To allow all subtypes of a particular abstract type, you can use a function parameter:

```
julia> f(Int)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Type{Int64})

julia> f{T<:Integer}(::Type{T}) = "integer method, got $T"
f (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> f(Int)
"integer method, got Int64"
```

The ability to capture the specific type in question as a function parameter is powerful and frequently used.  Note that I didn't even need to specify an argument name — the only thing that matters in this case is the parameter within `Type{}`.

---

So that was a pretty long explanation for what's really a pretty short answer: You typically don't want to use `DataType`, since it won't cover all types in Julia. Instead you should use `Type` to describe the type of any or all types. Use `Type{T}` when you want to describe the type of `T` in particular.

Comment: `Type` should be preferred to `DataType` for most use cases, because `DataType` only includes certain types like `String` or `Number`, but not `Vector` or `Union{Int, Float64}`.

Comment: To more directly answer the OP's question, while many types are `DataType`s, not all are. All types are `Type`s. On v0.5 the concrete subtypes of `Type` are `DataType`, `TypeConstructor`, and `Union`; on 0.6 this list is `DataType`, `BottomType`, `Union`, and `UnionAll`.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for the correction. I'll edit this when I get a chance.

Comment: In newer versions of Julia (1.X), the version with a function parameter should be written as ```f(::Type{T}) where {T<:Integer} = "integer method, got $T"```